# Markdown formatting of tag wiki excerpts in /review

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, tag-wiki, review

Tag wiki excerpts are *plain text*. The description when editing tag wikis states:

> The tag wiki excerpt is a brief **plain text** introduction to the topic that the tag represents. It is shown at the top of tag question lists, and as a tooltip wherever the tag appears. Complete this first!

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

This means that Markdown does not work there:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Unfortunately, for users on `/review`, it is rendered as Markdown, and therefore can easily be approved although clearly attempting to use unsupported formatting (see bold text on the left):

> [image]

---

Tag wiki excerpts in `/review` should *not* render Markdown, as it will just lead to fancy formatting in tag wiki excerpts by users used to using Markdown, that are then approved by higher-rep users without them being able to see that excerpts aren't actually formatted.

Comment: I only got to see the suggested edit that removes the formatting, but 1) it's still wrong there and 2) it's reasonable to assume regular *adding* the tag wiki behaves identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we shouldn't be giving you an option on those post types.  Starting with the next build, we'll remove the markdown-processed view button and show only the raw-text diff for tag wiki excerpts.

Thanks for the report!