# Synonymous meta tags about tagging

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonyms, meta-tags

There are some meta tags about tags that seems to be synonymous:

- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) is a synonym of [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).
- [tag-synonym-request](/questions/tagged/tag-synonym-request) is a synonym of [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms).
- [tag-wiki-suggestion](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-suggestion) is a synonym of [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not. You can discuss a topic without posting a request for changes.

As examples, see [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3810/markdown-formatting-of-tag-wiki-excerpts-in-review) and [this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4088/retagging-questions-with-the-answer) topic, both of which aren't suggestions or requests.

OTOH, the request and suggestion tags allow users to quickly search for topics that are about these specific and rather common issues.