# Why do we have both [retag-request] and [tag-synonym-request] on meta?

Tags: support, meta, tagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synonymous meta tags about tagging](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4411/synonymous-meta-tags-about-tagging)

Why do we have both [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) and [tag-synonym-request](/questions/tagged/tag-synonym-request) on meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both exist, because they refer to different kinds of requests.

#### Tag synonym requests

These are about creation of *tag synonyms*, i.e. connecting two tags such that using them is equivalent, with both essentially having the same questions list. An example is [osx-lion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-lion) (the "real" tag) and [osx-10.7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx-10.7) (the synonym).

While users can, in theory, set up tags themselves, this requires answer scores of 5 or more for users that'd vote about it, which is often too much, so this requires diamond moderators to handle.

#### Retag requests

These are mainly requests to disambiguate ambiguous tags (like e.g. [cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cd), which can be both compact disks and the `cd` command line command), or *changing a tag's name*, or maybe deleting useless tags.